# VSCode snippet: add variable number of objects to a class constructor

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I am trying to create a simple snippet that allows me to create JS Constructors. So far, what I have is

```
"class constructor": {
    "prefix": "class",
    "body": [
        "class ${1:ClassName} {",
            "\t\tconstructor({${2:thisName}: ${2}}) {",
                "\t\t\tthis.${2} = ${2}",
            "\t}",
        "}"
    ],
    "description": "class constructor template"
},
```

This works as expected, but what I am trying to see if it is possible to add multiple entries which also creates a new line for `this`, but in this case, the snippet runs its course once I fill in the details for `$2{thisName}`. What I am hoping for is the ability to add multiple key value pairs.

So instead of it ending at:

```
class ClassName {
  constructor({ thisName:  thisName}) {
    this. thisName =  thisName
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to add other items so that it looks like; where a new line for `this.another = another` is created automatically.

```
class ClassName {
  constructor({ thisName:  thisName, another: another}) {
    this. thisName = thisName
    this.another = another // this is create
 }
```

}

The `${3}..` doesn't work here because there could be any amount of items.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
"class constructor": {
  "prefix": "class",
  "body": [

    "class ${1:ClassName} {",
          "\t\tconstructor({${2/([^,]+)([,\\s]*|)/$1: $1${2:+, }/g}}) {",
          "${2/([^,]+)([,\\s]*|)/\t\t\tthis.$1 = $1${2:+\n}/g}",
          "\t}",
      "}"
  ],
  "description": "class constructor template"
},
```

[image: snippet with multiple call arguments]

See my answer at [Make a vscode snippet that can use a variable number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58225204/make-a-vscode-snippet-that-can-use-a-variable-number-of-arguments/58228253#58228253) for more explanation.

You can use any number of arguments in a snippet as long as you capture them in the same regex capture group - here each arg is in capture group $1.

Then **each one** is replaced!  In your case by `\t\t\tthis.$1 = $1${2:+\n` the second time.  After the tabs, the capture group is used in `this.$1 = $1`

Then capture group 2 is inspected `${2:+\n}`.  It either has the `,` or nothing.  If it has something, add a `\n`, otherwise nothing will be added.

For this regex to work you should enter your args as

`arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4`

-- with comma separators (withor without spaces after the commas).  After your last argument hit `tab` to fire the snippet transform.