# Visual Studio Code doesn't hint the __init__() formal parameters when trying to assign them into a instance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-hinting

It's common to assign local parameter into a instance within `__init__()` function in a class.

[image]

When using Pycharm, when typing `self.`, the IDE will hint formal parameters of the constructor, so we can quickly assign them to a instance.

But when using vscode, there is nothing to hint when typing `self.`, so we have to write the parameters' name once again, which is troublesome and more likely cause typo.

Is there a way to quickly assign the parameters in `__init__()` to a instance in python when using vscode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make VS Code Autocomplete Python Class Attribute Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63253433/how-to-make-vs-code-autocomplete-python-class-attribute-initialization)

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)